# Delete not important words

Tags: shell

I have:
an File with words: importantwords.txt (multiple lines, space separated, containing words)
Example:

```
ALMOST
APPARENTLY
COULD
DEPEND
.
.
.
```

and I have text files: 01news.txt,..., 10news.txt (News as a text).
Example:

During the short period of time between acquisition and allocation, the executive directors of the Company are deemed to be interested in those shares. The Company announces that the following transactions took place in relation to the SIP on Tuesday.

Now, I want to delete from 01news.txt, ... 10news.txt  all the words which are not in 
importantwords.txt

How could I do that? I tried it with sed, but I am newbie. Can you help please?

Comment: What is the form of your files? Are they English prose (sentences) or are they a a list of words?

Comment: Hello Peter, they are all in english as natural text. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for file in *news.txt
do
   awk 'FNR==NR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) impt[$i];next }
   { 
      for(j=1;j<=NF;j++) { 
        if ( toupper($j) in impt)  {
           printf "%s ", $j 
        }
      }
        print ""     
   } ' importantwords.txt $file > tmp && mv tmp $file

done
```

Comment: @tina, one thing to remember: if "WORD" is an important word, and the news file contains "this is a word." (with a period), then "word." will be removed -- awk uses whitespace as a separator, not punctuation.